# Javascript Errors when Debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, visual-studio-2013

I've just opened up a website for the first time in VS2013 and I'm getting Javascript exceptions when I run debugger:

```
Unhandled exception at line 194, column 21 in http://localhost:49809/

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

And here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
           $('#one').ContentSlider({
                width: '960px',
                height: '250px',
                speed: 400,
                easing: 'easeOutSine'
            });
      });
 </script>
```

Click Continue and I get a further exception:

```
Unhandled exception at line 37, column 59140 in http://localhost:52306/27fadf043d464a019907842c2a5a764e/browserLink

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: plusone
```

This website works fine live and debugs without issue in VS2012. I have a suspicion it's to do with referring to remote Javascript blocks (`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">`). Is there a permissions setting I need to amend?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Numb

Comment: You should have local fallbacks for when a CDN file can't be retrieved. For example: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Comment: What @ahren said + you should target a specific version, not `jquery-latest.min.js`. What will happen if you use a method which is valid today but removed tomorrow?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Point taken on latest. The only way to stop the exceptions was to comment the code out completely. Also none of my images or CSS is referencing correctly either in debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though your script manager adds in the jquery reference in the body tag of a master page.
You're putting in your own script and referencing jquery using the '$' symbol before the master page gets to the body tag.

Just move your own script to after the body. If you're using a content placeholder then move the content placeholder after the body (and not in the 'head' section).

Answer (score 28):

This seems to be a bug in the new Browser Link feature of VS 2013. See [Browser Link Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx). It is a way for dynamic communication between a running app and the Visual Studio.

From that article, you can turn off the feature by adding the following line to Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I've got a VS2013 VM as well as VS2013 installed locally. Error only occurs on the VM. Strange...

Comment: Or even when you are not running the project - ala hosting site in IIS but having the Web Site open in Visual Studio causes this for me.  <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" /> is another issue I've come across.