# Runtime error in ASP .Net ColorPickerExtender in AJAX control toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

I am using Visual studio 2013 and few controls in asp .net AJAX Control Toolkit.

Using the ComboBox and works fine. following is a sample of ComboBox control which works good.

```
 <div>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Combo Box: "></asp:Label>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <ccl:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"></ccl:ComboBox>
 </div>
```

But when I use the "ColorPickerExtender" I am getting A runtime javascipt error which I didn't find any way to get rid of and make this work

Following is a sample of the ToolPicker that I am trying with

```
  <div>  
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
       <ccl:ColorPickerExtender ID="ColorPickerExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupButtonID="Button1" SampleControlID="Button1"></ccl:ColorPickerExtender>
  </div>
```

Following is a screenshot in the Runtime javacript error that I am getting.

[image]

If anyone knows why I am getting this and to get rid of it that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try this [Javascript Errors when Debugging in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244048/javascript-errors-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Hi Thanks. This can not be my reason as I am not using any masterpages or any javascript codes written by me. As it didn't work in original project created a new test project and only it contains a web Form and the two divs I have indicated in the question...

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/post/3442754.aspx

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue.  Are you sure you've added all the scripts you need?  It seems to be saying that Sys.Extended.UI.ColorPickerBehavior is undefined.